# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined with items actually being pushed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, undefined

I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined but yet all the information is being pushed to the database correctly.  So why would it throw this error?

```
router.post("/item/:id", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  Item.findById(req.params.id, (err, item) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    var soldItem = {
      id: item._id,
      item: item.name,
      askPrice: item.price
    };
    var soldPrice = req.body.soldPrice;
    var soldQuantity = req.body.soldQuantity;
    var itemSold = { soldItem: soldItem, soldPrice: soldPrice, soldQuantity: soldQuantity };
    SoldItem.create(itemSold, (err, sold) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        item.solditems.push(sold);
        item.save();
        req.flash("success", "Item Sold");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can we take a look at your mongoose schema for `SoldItem`?

Comment: definitely your `solditems` does not contain `array`

Comment: Check your item collection you must not have solditems there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `solditems` on `item` is `undefined` and you are calling `push` on it.

Change

`item.solditems.push(sold);`

to

```
item.solditems = item.solditems || []; // if solditems undefined set to empty array
item.solditems.push(sold);
```